# Restart function inside Python Flask app.route

Tags: python, function, flask

I have 3 app.routes in Flask, like that:

```
@app.route('/page')
def page_with_buttons():
    return render_template('page_with_buttons.html')

@app.route('/api/run_function')
def run_function():
    # some function, which long execution time
    run_some_function() 
    return {'status':'ok'}

@app.route('/api/stop_function')
def stop_function():
    # - there need to stop function while execution
    return {'status':'ok'}
```

And simple template with AJAX:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="btn" id="run_function">Run Function</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" id="stop_function">Stop Function</a>

    <script>
        $('#run_function').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/run_function'
            });
        });

        $('#stop_function').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/stop_function'
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How i can programmatically abort this function without reload entire server?

Comment: You could run that function in background thread. And stop that thread. Although you'll soon run into issues due to [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). In your current approach `/api/run_function` will not return until `run_some_function()` finishes execution and returns. This means there will be no function to stop  in the call to `/api/stop_function`

Comment: What is the best way, use redis and celery?

Comment: Yes. You need async background job. For this celery and rq are the recommended solutions (beanstalkd is also noteworthy but requires more coding). If you think tahts too much work you can launch a subprocess to do the job and can interrupt it (or kill it) to stop it using message passing or issuing kill sigkill/sigterm